# Showing surjection for the question: $U_{32}/N\cong U_{16}$

Tags: group-theory

For the following question:
I have two questions, one of them is about showing surjection of a function, another is clarification about showing the function being well defined.  I will ask that in a separate post.  Can someone please check my work for errors or mistakes.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Show that $U_{32}/N\cong U_{16}$ where $N$ is the subgroup $\{1,17\}$, $U_{32}=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31\}$ and $U_{16}=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$

The cosets as elements in $U_{32}/N$ are $\{N, N3, N5, N7, N9, N11, N13, N15, N17, N19, N21, N23, N25, N27, N29, N31\}$ which are grouped into eight distinct equivalence classes: $N=N17, N3=N19, N5=N21, N7=N23, N9=N25, N11=N27, N13=N29, N15=N31$ and $\cup_{a\in U_{32}} N[a]_{32}=U_{32}$

I am suppose to write out an explicit map sending $U_{32}/N$ to $U_{16}$ and show that it is homomorphic and bijective.  Let $f(N[a]_{32})=[b]_{16}$, where $a\in U_{32}$ and $b\in U_{16}$.  For homomorphism, we let $x, y\in [a]_{32}$, then $f(N[xy]_{32})=[xy]_{16}=[x]_{16}[y]_{16}=f(N[x]_{32})f(N[y]_{32})$. Next I need to show $f$ is surjective, then since the domain and range of $f$ are both finite, I can conclude the function is bijective.

If for any $[b]_{16}\in U_{16},$ we have $[b]_{16}\equiv [a]_{16}$ where $[a]_{16}\in U_{16}$, but $16=8\times 2$ then $[b]_{2}\equiv [a]_{2}$ and $[b]_{8}\equiv [a]_{8}$.  Similarly $32=16\times 2$, and since we already have $[b]_{2}\equiv [a]_{2}$ and $[b]_{16}\equiv [a]_{16}$ implies $[b]_{32}\equiv [a]_{32}$.  But $[a]_{32}\in U_{32}$ and $[a]_{32}\in U_{32}/N$, meaning there exist some $[c]_{32}\in N[x]_{32}$ since $N\subset U_{32}$ so that $[b]_{16}\equiv[c]_{32}$, or $[b]_{16}\equiv[17c]_{32}$.  Hence we have shown that for any $[b]_{16}\in U_{16}$, we can find a $[c]_{32}\in U_{32}/N$, so that $f(N[c]_{32})=[b]_{16}$.

I implicitly use the following properties about congruence:

1. If $a\equiv b (mon p)$ and $a\equiv b (mod q)$, then $a\equiv b (mod pq)$
2. If $n=pq$, then $a\equiv b (mon p)$ and $a\equiv b (mod q)$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `$x\equiv y\pmod{p}$` for $x\equiv y\pmod{p}$.